# Does continuous extension of a function and its densely defined derivative imply everywhere differentiability?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a closed set, and let $U \subset V$ be open as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and dense in $V$. Let $f:V \to \mathbb R$ and $G: V \to \mathbb R^n$ be continuous, with $G = \nabla f$ on $U$. Does it follow that $G = \nabla f$ on the interior of $V$? To put it another way, is $(f,G)$ a Whitney field?

The obvious thing to do is the following: let $x \in V \setminus U$. We want to show that $f(x+h) - f(x) - \langle G(x),h \rangle = o(|h|).$ Choose $x_\epsilon$ arbitrarily close to $x$ in $U$, and write $$f(x+h) - f(x) - \langle G(x),h \rangle = f(x+h) - f(x_\epsilon) - \langle G(x_\epsilon),h-x_\epsilon \rangle + f(x_\epsilon) - f(x) $$ $$+ \langle G(x_\epsilon) - G(x), h \rangle - \langle G(x_\epsilon), x - x_\epsilon \rangle.$$ We control the first three terms using the differentiability of $f$ at $x_\epsilon$, the next two using the continuity of $f$ and the fact taht we can take $|x - x_\epsilon|$ as small as we like, and similarly for the last two. Unfortunately, we choose $x_\epsilon$ depending on $h$, and we don't know that $f$ is uniformly differentiable on $U$, so this doesn't quite work.

Comment: Is it true that the interior of $V$ is $U$ ?

Comment: No, the interior of $V$ need not be $U$. For example, $U$ could be the interior of $V$ less a point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false. Take, for example, $V = [0,1]$, $U = [0,1] \setminus C$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, $f$ the Cantor function, and $G = 0$.